# Sharing Questions With Your Followers

Tags: support, announcement

We've recently noticed that on June 13th, Stack Exchange removed the share buttons from the left side of questions on the network. The developers [do not plan to add them back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140190/please-add-back-the-social-networking-links-on-beta-sites).

We believe that sharing questions on Project Management Stack Exchange is critical to promoting a broader interest in the site as a whole. It's up to our community to spread the word and help bring more experts and enthusiasts into our community.

I did some searching, and I found a [StackApps UserScript that will add the share links to the "link" box](https://stackapps.com/questions/3514/add-share-buttons-to-the-link-box) that appears below questions. It's easy to install. I literally clicked "Install" in my Google Chrome browser and was instantly able to share a question on Twitter.

https://stackapps.com/questions/3514/add-share-buttons-to-the-link-box

Answer (score 1):

Yeessss! I'm happy to announce that [Stack Exchange added back the social networking share links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140190/please-add-back-the-social-networking-links-on-beta-sites), so forget the browser add-on!

Let's take advantage of this! Sharing links to interesting questions and answers can get them more views and more attention.